# Указатель на родительский класс

Tags: указатели, c++

```
class A{
public: mc
myclass * mc;
A(mc*m){mc=m;};

class B{

public: B(){}
  work(){
// здесь нужно работать с методами и объектами одного из экземпляров класса myclass через указатель, который передается классу A
}

}

}
```

Экземпляр класса **A** создается в классе myclass(для каждого **myclass** может быть несколько экземпляров), в то же время для каждого **A** может быть несколько созданных в нем экземпляров класса **B**. 
Внутри B нужно работать с методами и объектами класса **A**, в котором В был инициализирован, но в то же время, работать и с myclass, в котором был инициализирован **A**. То есть по иерархии.

*IntelliSense* предлагает сделать указатель mc статическим. Тогда да, действительно я могу работать в классе **В** с методами класса myclass, но это не подходит, так как у меня может быть несколько экземпляров **myclass**.

Единственным вариантом реализации такой задачи является передача `this'а` внутри **А** при создании экземпляров класса **B**? Таким образом, каждый экземпляр B будет хранить указатель на текущий **A**, в котором он был создан

Comment: Ну, не единственным, но возможно самым простым.

Для того, чтобы понять, кто из объектов должен знать о чём, а какие полномочия делегировать другим, **не приводите пример** с классами `A` и `B`! Дайте классам осмысленные названия, которые отображают предметную область, тогда станет сразу понятно, что и как нужно делегировать, и кому о ком следует знать.

Comment: думаю, это на много усложнило бы пример, если бы сюда просто выложил исходники с проекта с ogl

Comment: @Ni55aN: Судите сами. Если, допустим, у вас `A` — это начальник, а `B` — это работники, которые выполняют работу, то у `A` должен быть их список, но он не должен дёргать их методы, а передавать им задания (оформленные в виде структуры, например). Если `A` — покупатель, а `B` — кассы, то он должен выбрать на основе какого-то критерия единственную кассу, и дёргать её методы. И т. д.

Comment: смысл в том, что данный вопрос не привязан к какой-нибудь реализации. Не думаю, что ХэшКодовцев будет интересовать то, как на самом деле именуются классы в моем проекте

Comment: Если нужно работать с методами и объектами родительского класса, то, очевидно, без передачи этого объекта не обойтись. Можно, правда, передать не сам объект, а обёртку, делегирующую этому объекту часть вызовов. Также можно передавать объект не в конструкторе, а уже после создания. Чтобы использовать объекты выше по иерархии (`myclass`), можно, например, в классе `A` сделать метод `Myclass * getMyclass()` и вызывать его из `B`.

Comment: @Ni55aN: В том-то и дело, что «правильного» ответа, не привязанного к смыслу вашим классов, **не существует**. Ответ зависит от реальной семантики классов. Не зная предназначения классов, нельзя дать совет, не являющийся глупым. Для одной семантики один вариант правилен, а для другой этот же вариант является полной чушью.

Comment: @Ni55aN Возможно, вам стоит ещё раз подумать над архитектурой, если текущая структура заводит вас в тупик.

Comment: ни о каком "тупике" речь не шла, вопрос лишь в практической части